# What's the difference between “dessous” and “en dessous”?

Tags: indications-de-lieu, locutions

For instance ,which one is correct? And why?

> Le numéro de série est marqué **en dessous**.
>
> Le numéro de série est marqué **dessous**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that you can use a complement with "en dessous" ou "sous", whereas you can't with "dessous"; thus, you can say this;

- le numéro de série est marqué **en dessous de/sous**  la date de fabrication.

These two words are prépositions.

When you use "dessous", which is not a preposition (so you can't use nouns after it) but an adverb, you must specify in the context the thing under which is what you are talking about;

- La date de fabrication se trouve au dos du couvercle; le numéro de série se trouve **dessous**. *The number is under the date.*